# Why should I use `all_of` to select columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tibble

I'm currently using R and came across the function `all_of` in the tidyverse. What does this function exists for? It seems like I can use just `x` at every point where `all_of(x)` can be used..

**Example:**

library(tidyverse)

```
tb <- tibble(a=1:3, b=1:3, c=1:3)
x <- c("a", "b")

tb %>% select(all_of(x))
tb %>% select(x)

tb %>$ select(-all_of(x))
tb %>% select(-x)
```

The two lines with `all_of` yield the same return values as the ones without the extra function. Why should I bother using them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a really nice question!

It is to make it clear about what you really want when selecting columns. Imagine this simple situation:

```
library(tidyverse)

tb <- tibble(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, z = 1:3)
x <- c("x", "y")

tb %>% select(x)
```

Do you see that? It is not clear whether you want `x` as external vector here and thus select two columns (`x` and `y`), or if you want to select only one column `x`.

That's why you should use `all_of()`, which says that you want to select column names from an external vector.

More information can be found in [tidyselect docs](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html).

Comment: So `all_of` is of use, when I want to select columns stored in a variable whose name is a column as well. Should I use it always as good standard?

Comment: Exactly! And when refering to external vector, yes, you probably should use it as a good standard. I think that _not using_ it prints a warning message to the console.